# csv file upload in php inserts only first row in database

Tags: php, csv

I want to upload csv file in mysql database in php. I am using,

```
$handle = fopen($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], "r");
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,',','"')) !== FALSE) {
    // insert into database...
}
fclose($handle);
```

But, it inserts only first row of the file.

EDIT:

when I am trying to print_r `$data` within while loop, then also it's giving me only one row.

Comment: Can you post your code for `fgetcsv`?

Comment: @MrGlass [The fgetcsv docs are here.](http://php.net/fgetcsv)

Comment: I have updated question.. Do you want to see mysql query?

Comment: Sry, I had no idea that function existed. Learn something new every day.

Comment: Sounds like the rest of the file isn't valid CSV, so it's getting an error reading it.

Comment: What is `count($data)` on the first line? Maybe it's not recognizing the line endings, so it's treating the entire file as one line.

Comment: `count($data)` is : 3434 . And I have 6 rows in file. why is it like that?

Comment: I caught error.. Actually, It was datatype error in mysql. I checked in error log. Thanks everybody for your efforts.